# How to run Get-Credential once then store credentials and reuse credentials in the same session

Tags: powershell, loops, credentials

This works as expected, it runs in menu loop and I'm able to store and decrypt credentials.

However because this is looped menu (in order to be able to run different commands) it asks for user/password dialog every time the loop restarts..

Anyone have any ideas on how to change this?, so that user/password is entered once then subsequent runs it does not re-ask for the password for that session?

I'm thinking I need a condition on get-credentials but I'm not sure ..(partial but relevant section, because the menu is quite lengthy..

Appreciate any input

```
LoadMenuSystem
$Key = New-Object Byte[] 32
[Security.Cryptography.RNGCryptoServiceProvider]::Create().GetBytes($Key)
$Key | Out-File AES.key

(get-credential).Password | ConvertFrom-SecureString -key (get-content AES.key) | set-content "AESPassword.txt"

$password = Get-Content AESPassword.txt | ConvertTo-SecureString -Key (Get-Content AES.key)

$credential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PsCredential($env:userName,$password)

$ServerName = Read-Host -Prompt "What is the server name?"

$Command = ".\myProgram"
$arg1  =  '-t'
$arg2 = $credential.GetNetworkCredential().username+'@'+$ServerName
$arg3 = '-pw'
$arg4 = $credential.GetNetworkCredential().Password
$arg5 = $scriptcmd
```

Comment: Can you move the credential handling outside of the loop?

Comment: I did try that, it runs once and then the menu reloads and it exists prematurely.. not sure why..

trying something like this:
    if ($credential -eq
    [system.management.Automation.PsCredential]::Empty { Invoke-Command (get-credential).Password | ConvertFrom-SecureString -key (get-content AES.key) | set-content "AESPassword.txt"  ...something like that...just need to get syntax right ;)

Comment: This is now working (sort of) within loop, it does not ask for get-credentials dialog, but now reads from encrypted password/key file... Need to delete those files and retest to see if it runs get-credentials in order to rebuild the encrypted/password again..The menu loop breaks as before, but it already was doing that ... closer :)